# Kafka Source Connect does not seem to do anything

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I tried creating this connector from Confluent Control Center and clicking Continue on the first screen does not do anything, does not prompt for an error. When I ran it from the bash it won't stop, I don't see any extraordinary errors but it doesn't do anything either. How can I find out what is wrong with my configuration, is there another log or so to look at?

Schema config

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
rest.port=8084
plugin.path=/confluent-4.1.0/share/java
```

Connect config

```
name=XXX_SOURCE
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=10
batch.max.rows=1000
connection.url=jdbc:as400://<IP>;<DATABASE>;
connection.user=<USER>
connection.password=<PASSWORD>
query=SELECT * FROM (SELECT c.*, TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(cast(mod(CAST(MSDAST AS INT),10000) * 10000 +  CAST(MSDAST AS INT) / 1000000 * 100 +  mod(CAST(MSDAST AS INT) / 10000, 100) AS varchar(30)) || ' ' || CASE WHEN CAST(MSTIST AS INT) / 10000 >= 10 THEN cast(CAST(MSTIST AS INT) / 10000 AS varchar(30)) ELSE '0' || cast(CAST(MSTIST AS INT) / 10000 AS varchar(30)) END || right(cast(mod(CAST(MSTIST AS INT), 100000) AS varchar(30)),4),'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') AS DATEADDED FROM <DATABASE>.<TABLE> c) d
mode=timestamp
timestamp.column.name=DATEADDED
topic.prefix=XXX_TOPIC
poll.interval.ms=60000
```

Log

```
bin]$ sudo ./connect-standalone /kafka/salesforce-schema.properties /kafka/crmmastp.properties
[2018-04-24 16:11:06,301] INFO Kafka Connect standalone worker initializing ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:67)
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerInfo:71)
[2018-04-24 16:11:06,315] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:76)
[2018-04-24 16:11:06,333] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-control-center (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:08,282] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-control-center/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:08,298] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/schema-registry (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,110] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/schema-registry/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,122] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-common (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,175] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-common/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,176] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-ibmmq (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,268] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-ibmmq/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,269] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,269] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:09,269] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:11,966] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:11,966] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:11,966] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:12,110] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-s3 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:14,672] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-s3/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:14,672] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:14,706] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:15,672] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:15,672] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:15,672] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:15,679] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-rest (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,218] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-rest/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,224] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-support-metrics (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,286] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-support-metrics/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,287] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-replicator (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,735] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-replicator/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,735] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,735] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,735] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-security (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,736] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-security/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,736] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-serde-tools (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,828] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:16,829] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/ksql (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:17,714] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/ksql/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:17,723] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-hdfs (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,648] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-hdfs/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,649] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.hdfs.tools.SchemaSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,649] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,688] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,798] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jms/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,799] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,934] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,934] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:19,936] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:20,290] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:20,290] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:20,290] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:20,333] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-rebalancer (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,037] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/confluent-rebalancer/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,051] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/monitoring-interceptors (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,254] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,255] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/camus (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,691] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/camus/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,699] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-activemq (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,785] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-activemq/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,785] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,786] INFO Loading plugin from: /confluent-4.1.0/share/java/rest-utils (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-04-24 16:11:21,907] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/rest-utils/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,179] INFO Registered loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,180] INFO Added aliases 'ActiveMQSourceConnector' and 'ActiveMQSource' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,181] INFO Added aliases 'ElasticsearchSinkConnector' and 'ElasticsearchSink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,181] INFO Added aliases 'HdfsSinkConnector' and 'HdfsSink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,181] INFO Added aliases 'IbmMQSourceConnector' and 'IbmMQSource' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,181] INFO Added aliases 'JdbcSinkConnector' and 'JdbcSink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,181] INFO Added aliases 'JdbcSourceConnector' and 'JdbcSource' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,182] INFO Added aliases 'JmsSourceConnector' and 'JmsSource' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,182] INFO Added aliases 'ReplicatorSourceConnector' and 'ReplicatorSource' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,182] INFO Added aliases 'S3SinkConnector' and 'S3Sink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,182] INFO Added aliases 'FileStreamSinkConnector' and 'FileStreamSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,183] INFO Added aliases 'FileStreamSourceConnector' and 'FileStreamSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,183] INFO Added aliases 'MockConnector' and 'Mock' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,183] INFO Added aliases 'MockSinkConnector' and 'MockSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,183] INFO Added aliases 'MockSourceConnector' and 'MockSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,186] INFO Added aliases 'VerifiableSinkConnector' and 'VerifiableSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,186] INFO Added aliases 'VerifiableSourceConnector' and 'VerifiableSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,186] INFO Added aliases 'AvroConverter' and 'Avro' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,186] INFO Added aliases 'JsonConverter' and 'Json' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,187] INFO Added aliases 'StringConverter' and 'String' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,187] INFO Added aliases 'JsonConverter' and 'Json' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,187] INFO Added alias 'SimpleHeaderConverter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,187] INFO Added aliases 'StringConverter' and 'String' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,188] INFO Added alias 'RegexRouter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,188] INFO Added alias 'TimestampRouter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,189] INFO Added alias 'ValueToKey' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,202] INFO StandaloneConfig values:
        access.control.allow.methods =
        access.control.allow.origin =
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
        internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        key.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
        listeners = null
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        offset.flush.interval.ms = 60000
        offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
        offset.storage.file.filename = /tmp/connect.offsets
        plugin.path = [/confluent-4.1.0/share/java]
        rest.advertised.host.name = null
        rest.advertised.listener = null
        rest.advertised.port = null
        rest.host.name = null
        rest.port = 8084
        ssl.client.auth = none
        task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
        value.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneConfig:279)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,202] INFO Creating Kafka admin client (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils:43)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,208] INFO AdminClientConfig values:
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 120000
        retries = 5
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:279)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,291] WARN The configuration 'plugin.path' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,292] WARN The configuration 'internal.key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,292] WARN The configuration 'rest.port' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,292] WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,292] WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,292] WARN The configuration 'internal.key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,294] WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.file.filename' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,294] WARN The configuration 'internal.value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,294] WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,294] WARN The configuration 'internal.value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,294] WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,294] WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,294] WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:287)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,295] INFO Kafka version : 1.1.0-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:109)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,295] INFO Kafka commitId : 93e03414f72c2485 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:110)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,498] INFO Cluster ID: 7_19QWuYTY-rSypibzffYg (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:265)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,503] INFO Kafka cluster ID: 7_19QWuYTY-rSypibzffYg (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils:59)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,520] INFO Logging initialized @18849ms (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:186)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,546] INFO Added connector for http://:8084 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:110)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,976] INFO Advertised URI: http://192.168.217.92:8084/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:248)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,981] INFO Kafka version : 1.1.0-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:109)
[2018-04-24 16:11:24,981] INFO Kafka commitId : 93e03414f72c2485 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:110)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,086] INFO JsonConverterConfig values:
        converter.type = key
        schemas.cache.size = 1000
        schemas.enable = false
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig:279)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,087] INFO JsonConverterConfig values:
        converter.type = value
        schemas.cache.size = 1000
        schemas.enable = false
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig:279)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,094] INFO Kafka Connect standalone worker initialization took 18791ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:92)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,094] INFO Kafka Connect starting (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:49)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,094] INFO Herder starting (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:71)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,094] INFO Worker starting (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:139)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,094] INFO Starting FileOffsetBackingStore with file /tmp/connect.offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:59)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,098] INFO Worker started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:144)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,098] INFO Herder started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:73)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,099] INFO Starting REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:155)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,186] INFO jetty-9.2.24.v20180105 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:327)
Apr 24, 2018 4:11:25 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,792] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@61ae0d43{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:744)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,801] INFO Started http_8084@51bddd98{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8084} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:266)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,801] INFO Started @20130ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:379)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,802] INFO Advertised URI: http://192.168.217.92:8084/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:248)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,802] INFO REST server listening at http://192.168.217.92:8084/, advertising URL http://192.168.217.92:8084/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:207)
[2018-04-24 16:11:25,802] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:55)
```

Comment: Can you check if your connector started or not? Looks like your Kafka connect worker has started correctly. Hit rest server(http://192.168.217.92:8084/) and see if you see any connectors(XXX_SOURCE) if yes then try hitting url (http://192.168.217.92:8084/XXX_SOURCE) to see passed in connector config.